# Is there a way to stop and restart a self hosted Python script using Github Actions?

Tags: python, linux, github-actions

I have a project in which one of the tests consists of running a process indefinitely in order to collect data on the program execution.

It's a Python script that runs locally on a Linux machine, but I'd like for other people in my team to have access to it as well because there are specific moments where the process needs to be restarted.

Is there a way to set up a workflow on this machine that when dispatched, stops and restarts the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute commands on your Linux host via GH Actions and SSH. Take a look at this [action](https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action).

Comment: Thanks! I believe this solves my problem.